# How to scan a formatted string using fscanf()?

Tags: c, io

I have this file with multiple lines. Each line follows a format of

```
`userID:$An Integer$$String:`
```

For example:

```
pyc1:$1$$Tnq7a6/C1wwyKyt0V/.BP/:
pyc2:$6$$Tnq7a6/C1wwyKyt0V/.BP/:
```

How should I use `fscanf()` to retrieve the `userID`, the integer, and the string between `$$` and :`?

This is what I have now, but it is not working.

```
int main(){
    FILE * file = fopen("shadow.txt", "r");
    char line[256] = {0};
    char userID[30] = {0};
    int hashType;
    char hash[256] = {0};
    int result = fscanf(file, "%s :$ %d $$ %s :", userID, &hashType, hash);
    printf("%s\n", userID );
    printf("%d\n", hashType );
    printf("%s\n", hash );

}
```

I don't know much about the format I should specify for `fscanf()` to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: Does the line end at the colon?

Comment: @unwind the line in the file end with a carriage return

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The userID, Integer and hash is not scanning into the variables. It appears as the whole line from the file is scanned into userID

Comment: Why is that not part of your question ?

Comment: regarding: `FILE * file = fopen("shadow.txt", "r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the posted code, the returned value should be 3.  2) when using the '%s' format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field.  One less because a NUL byte is always appended by that specifier.  This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow.  Such overflow would be undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @Anlinyang, are you saying that the last line of the file does not end in a ':' followed (as all the other lines are) by a '\n'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a regex, like this for example:

```
fscanf (file, "%[^:]:$%d$$%[^:]:", userID, &hashType, hash);
```

I created a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V5wkxW/1) link that explains the regex expression used above.

---

PS: Don't forget to check for the return value of [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/), in order to ensure that everything was read parsed correctly. You want to parse three elements, thus the return value should be 3.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. So my understand for %[^:] is it will scan in any character except for : Is that correct?

Comment: Does all the regex rules can be applied inside %[]? Such as * for any number of characters

Comment: There are *many* things you can do with a regex expression @Anlinyang. Play around with it in the link I posted, if you like!

Comment: the '%[^:]' will input any characters, but will stop (and not input) the ':' when a ':' is encountered

Comment: this fails to check the returned value from `fscanf()`, so errors can occur and the code would not catch those errors.  Strongly suggest checking the returned value against 3.  Any other returned value means an error occurred

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(ret = fscanf(file," %[^:] : $ %d $$ %[^:] :",userID,&hashtype,hash))
{

    if(ret == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }

    printf("value of ret: %d\n",ret);
    printf("%s , %d , %s",userid,id,str);

    // . . .

}
```

here, int ret is:

- EOF, if the pointer is reached end of file.
- 0, if no input matched with the variable
- >0, number of matched variables with the file input

Comment: the correct value to be checking as returned from `fscanf()` is (in the current scenario) 3.   There are other error events possible besides EOF